# Show largest value after sentinel ends loop using a conditional statement

Tags: c++, sentinel

I need to create a program that will allow the users to enter a series of
integers with 0 as the sentinel. At the end, the largest integer will be displayed.

I originally had the statement `largest = value` under the if statement but changed it to a conditional statement which makes more sense to me since the previous way I had it just gave me the last value before the sentinel was entered. It seems to give me the "right" output, but is the way I set it up with the conditional statement correct? If not, how can I fix it?

### Original output

```
This program finds the largest integer in a list.
Enter 0 to signal the end of the input.

Please enter an integer: 21

Please enter an integer: 15

Please enter an integer: 9

Please enter an integer: 6

Please enter an integer: 3

Please enter an integer: 0

The largest value is 3.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

### Current output

```
This program finds the largest integer in a list.
Enter 0 to signal the end of the input.

Please enter an integer: 15

Please enter an integer: 200

Please enter an integer: 3

Please enter an integer: 5

Please enter an integer: 21

Please enter an integer: 0

The largest value is 200.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

### Source code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

const int SENTINEL = 0;

/* Main Program */
int main()
{
    
    cout << "This program finds the largest integer in a list.";
    cout << "\nEnter " << SENTINEL << " to signal the end of the input." << endl;

    int largest = SENTINEL;

    while (true)
    {
        int value; 
        cout << "\nPlease enter an integer: ";  
        cin >> value;

        if (value == SENTINEL) 
            break;
        largest = (value > largest) ? value : largest; 
    }

    cout << "\nThe largest value is " << largest << "." << endl;

    cout << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: add in `if ( !cin ) break;` after `cin >> value` otherwise you will go into an inifinite loop if they type something strange.  You might also want to start with `int largest = INT_MIN;` so that your program copes with negative numbers, and also try to handle the case where the first value they enter is the sentinel.

Comment: I followed your first suggestion and ran the program and tested out what would happen if I entered a symbol like !. The last sentence just said The largest value is 0.

Comment: try entering a non-zero number , press enter, and then do `!` next time it says "Please enter an integer".

Comment: If I enter 8, then !, at the end, it will say The largest value is 0.

Comment: If the first value entered is 0, the program will stop prompting and display that the largest value is 0 which makes sense since 0 is the sentinel value and is meant to stop the loop which prompts for more values.

Comment: OK, your compiler is being friendly and treating `int value` as `int value = 0` .Lucky or unlucky depending on how you want to look at it  :)  When you enter `!`, then `cin >> value` does not change `value`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `8` is read into `value`, then the `!` fails parsing which from C++11 is required to reset `value` to `0` (unspecified behaviour in C++03), coincidentally matching the `SENTINEL` and terminating the loop.  The [output I see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fab8ed830dfb06b) is `8` - consistent with that - not the `0` that Mary reports above, and which I can't explain.

Comment: @TonyD if your description is correct, then `8` is read successfully the first time, and the second time `0` is read

Comment: @MattMcNabb: depends on what you consider "read" - `value` is set but not to anything read from the stream - the stream is left in an error state.  My points were just that your earlier "treating `int value` as `int value = 0`" was strange speculation because `value`'s overwritten with `8` and any prior value is irrelevant, and that "enter `!`, then `cin >> value` does not change `value`" is not true of C++11.

Comment: @TonyD Yep, got that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few minor suggestions in inline comments, for whatever educational value you can extract from them...

```
#include <iostream> 

const int SENTINEL = 0;

int main()
{
    // can continue input across lines, and rarely need to use endl...
    // (any input attempt from cin will flush cout first)
    std::cout << "This program finds the largest integer in a list.\n"
        "Enter " << SENTINEL << " to signal the end of the input.\n";

    int num_inputs = 0;
    int largest;
        // before, shouldn't have used sentinel here - if input all negative
        //   largest would be 0 in error...
        // now won't use unless we see actual inputs so no need to init

    int value;
    while (std::cout << "\nPlease enter an integer: " &&
           std::cin >> value)  // use cin so unparsable input breaks
    {
        if (value == SENTINEL) 
            break;
        if (++num_inputs == 1)
            largest = value;
        else if (value > largest)
            largest = value;
    }

    if (num_inputs > 0)
        std::cout << "\nThe largest value is " << largest << ".\n\n";
    system("PAUSE");  // for Windoze
}
```

Using `num_inputs` lets us avoid outputing a message claiming to know the largest value when there were no non-sentinel inputs.

Yet another way to maintain `largest` is:

```
else
    largest = std::max(value, largest);
```

Regarding...

```
while (std::cout << "\nPlease enter an integer: " &&
       std::cin >> value)
```

...this ensures input that can not be parsed as an integer causes the loop to terminate (because `std::cin` gets set in an `eof`, `fail` and/or `bad` state, any of which causes the `std::istream::operator bool() const` operator to return `false` in a boolean evaluation context.  The trick of writing the prompt ("Please enter...") in the while condition is just so it's done before the first input attempt, then redone each time through the loop without having to repeat the same `std::cout << ...` source code at the end of the `while` loop.  It's slightly more correct too, as output to `std::cout` could fail and terminating the loop's not an unreasonable reaction to that, though people very rarely bother to test the success of `cout` or `cerr` output operations.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Tony D! It was very insightful and helped me fix the problem I had where the last statement kept saying "The largest value is 0".

Comment: Tony D, I did forget to ask, is it okay if the if, else if statements under the while loop were made into 3 separate if statements?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct in my opinion.

However, you can simply replace:

```
largest = (value > largest) ? value : largest;
```

by an equivalent `if` conditional statement:

```
if (value > largest){
    largest = value;
}
```

Also, note that just replace your declaration:

```
int largest = SENTINEL;
```

by

```
int largest =  INT_MIN;
```

where `INT_MIN` is minimum possible integer.